# Complex SQL query to combine rows

Tags: sql, join, state, combining-marks

I have 2 tables first is

```
Thread { code, itr_global,campaign, contact, start_time,duration}
segment {code,thread,start_time,duration,state}
```

There are multiple other joins but these 2 are major joins. 2 table are realted as thread.code=segment.thread.

In segment table there will be multiple rows for singl thread. I need to get values

campaign    start_time  duration    waititme    talk_time   hold_time   wrap_time

Where wait_time I can get as segment.state=7 & talke_time=segment.state=6 & wrap time as segment.state=8
I am not able to get all these values in single row as it will give me 3 diffrent rows for each record. How can I get all the values in single row as per above format.

Comment: I do not see an SQL query ?  (and please add the RDBMS you are using, and some sample data and desired output to make your problem clearer)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. Make it easy to assist you!

Answer (score 0):

You need some conditional aggregation `SUM(CASE...)` to get the result you want.

All this is based on my guesses about the structure and meaning of your tables, which you omitted from your question.

```sql
SELECT thread.code, thread.campaign,
       SUM(segment.duration) duration,
       SUM(CASE WHEN segment.state = 7 THEN segment.duration END) waittime,
       SUM(CASE WHEN segment.state = 6 THEN segment.duration END) talk_time,
       SUM(CASE WHEN segment.state = 8 THEN segment.duration END) wrap_time,
       42 hold_time, -- you didn't say how to get hold_time
       SUM(CASE WHEN segment.state = 8 THEN segment.duration END) wrap_time
  FROM Thread
  LEFT JOIN segment ON Thread.code = segment.thread
 GROUP BY  thread.code, thread.campaign
```